# How to simulate a user driving a route in a MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

I need to simulate how my application will look when a user is driving around for a demo. I have a MKMapView, how can I simulate the look of a user driving around which will use the map.userLocation functionality, which obviously will not be available in the demo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got something going, I just did essentially this

```
- (void)moveIcon:(MKAnnotationView*)locationView toLocation:(CLLocation*)newLoc
{
    LocationAnnotation* annotation = [[[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLoc.coordinate] autorelease];
    [locationView setAnnotation:annotation];
    [map setCenterCoordinate:newLoc.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Then I call this guy in a loop between all of my vertices with a slight delay. Works quite qell.

Answer (score 1):

No way to simulate in iPhone simulator. You'll need to load it onto your device and move around.

Comment: I didn't mean exactly simulate it using CoreLocation, jsut some way to animate a pin moving around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iPhone dev expert, but how does the map view receive the coordinates? If it's through a function that calls the CoreLocation API, could you possibly just write a function that randomly generates longitude and latitude values at a certain time interval and have your map view pull the coordinates from there instead? Just a thought.

Comment: The MapKit maps work like this for the pins you drop, but when you put your own location in (the blue circle), the MapKit uses the CoreLocation services internally.  Unfortunately, this won't work.

Comment: It receives them through a custom Annotation, all of the internals of this annotation are hidden so it is impossible to emulate.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) which claims to be able to simulate several features only available on the iPhone in the iPhone simulator include CoreLocation. I have not tried this myself so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

In order to simulate driving you'll need to establish 2 basic functionalities:

1. Reading CLLocations from an archive (which you'd log during the drive test with a device). Ideally you'll do this based on the timestamps on the locations, i.e. reproducing the exact same location updates which were received during the drive test.
2. Updating your MKAnnotationView's position on the map based on the locations read from log.

For part 1, take a look at [CLLocationDispatch](https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils/tree/master/CoreLocationUtils), a handy class which provides archiving/unarchiving of CLLocations and dispatches them to one or more listeners (using CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol).

For part 2, take a look at [Moving-MKAnnotationView](https://github.com/100grams/Moving-MKAnnotationView).

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way would be to subclass `MKUserLocation`:

```
class SimulatedUserLocation: MKUserLocation {
    private var simulatedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39, longitude: -76)
    override dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
            return simulatedCoordinate
        }
        set {
            simulatedCoordinate = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then add it as an annotation `mapView.addAnnotation(SimulatedUserLocation())`. (You might also want to hide the real location first `mapView.showsUserLocation = false`)

iOS would render the annotation exactly like the real user location.

`dynamic` is used on the property so that changing coordinate triggers KVO and moves it on the map.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is NO. Then, how about adding an abstraction layer between your code and MKMapKit? You can do xUnit tests for your objective.